# Using Vidyo and Callkit on iOS - Audio question

Tags: ios, voip, callkit, vidyo

I've integrated Vidyo with CallKit on iOS for VOIP, except for one issue: Audio is sometimes muted on connection, and either needs the microphone toggled twice, or stays muted.  I'm using the Vidyo.io resource to connect.  I know that Apple has special calls to enhance audio when using voip protocols, but I do not call these, because I think Vidyo is handling the audio here (plus I don't know what to call!).  Has anyone successfully integrated CallKit into Vidyo, and, if so, what do you do for Configure AVAudioSession?